# Double escaping HTML / Spring / JSP

Tags: html, spring, jsp, escaping

This is what gets rendered in the html source:

```
<li>Confirm Password doesn&amp;#39;t match password./li>
```

On the browser, this is read as: Confirm Password doesn&#39;t match password.

This is the code that generates this:

```
<spring:hasBindErrors name="profileAccount">
  <ul class="errorsList">
    <c:forEach items="${errors.allErrors}" var="error">
      <li><spring:message code="${error.code}"
          text="${error.defaultMessage}"
        /></li>
    </c:forEach>
  </ul>
</spring:hasBindErrors>
```

How can I prevent the double escaping?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/spring.tld.html#spring.tld.htmlEscape

and

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/spring.tld.html#spring.tld.message

The htmlEscape attribute.

Answer (score 1):

`spring:hasBindErrors` and `spring:message` *both* obey the default global HTML escaping setting (either via `defaultHtmlEscape` as a context param. or via the `htmlEscape` tag).

The end result is that `${error.defaultMessage}` will already have been escaped by the time it is passed into `<spring:message>`. You can work around this by disabling HTML escaping on one (but *not* the other). Example:

```
<spring:message htmlEscape="false" code="${error.code}" text="${error.defaultMessage}"/>
```